# Custom TableCellRenderer ignored by Look&Feel

Tags: java, swing, jtable, look-and-feel, nimbus

I have a JTable for which I have provided a custom TableCellRenderer that colors numeric cells in red/gray/green depending on their value (<0, 0, >0).

However, when I use the Nimbus L&F, the `label.setForeground()` method is ignored: when calling `label.getForeground()` I can see that the number has the right color, for example red, but on the screen it comes black. If I remove the L&F it works fine.

**Is there a way to gently ask the L&F to accept using my color for that cell?**

ps: I know that the [javadoc of `setForeground()`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/javax/swing/JComponent.html#setForeground%28java.awt.Color%29) is clear about the fact that the L&F might ignore the call, so I'm looking for a workaround.

Comment: Last I heard, Nimbus was considered very buggy.

Comment: @AndrewThompson Can you elaborate / provide references?

Comment: Try my results and the comment by kleopatra on [this thread](http://stackoverflow.com/q/8624040/418556).

Comment: @AndrewThompson OK thanks; assuming I still need to use Nimbus, is there a way to override its default behaviour in this specific instance?

Comment: I'm not sure.  I've never delved into the nitty-gritty of PLAFs, I just use them if they work.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

- think are complicated by using `JLabel`,
- if you'll use `Components` then there no needed to override `NimbusDefaults` or `Painter`,
- [sorry I have no ideas to playing](https://stackoverflow.com/q/9958004/714968) with `Nimbus` & `NimbusDefaults` & `Renderer`, because I have another favorite L&F [please read some more info about Look and Feels](https://stackoverflow.com/a/9382795/714968)
- (without override NimbusDefaults from JCheckBox, this issue are solved a few times on this forum)

[image]

```
import java.awt.*;
import javax.swing.*;
import javax.swing.table.*;

public class TablePrepareRenderer extends JFrame {

    private static final long serialVersionUID = 1L;
    private JTable table;

    public TablePrepareRenderer() {
        Object[] columnNames = {"Type", "Company", "Shares", "Price", "Boolean"};
        Object[][] data = {
            {"Buy", "IBM", new Integer(1000), new Double(80.50), false},
            {"Sell", "MicroSoft", new Integer(2000), new Double(6.25), true},
            {"Sell", "Apple", new Integer(3000), new Double(7.35), true},
            {"Buy", "Nortel", new Integer(4000), new Double(20.00), false}
        };
        DefaultTableModel model = new DefaultTableModel(data, columnNames) {

            private static final long serialVersionUID = 1L;

            @Override
            public Class getColumnClass(int column) {
                return getValueAt(0, column).getClass();
            }
            /*@Override
            public Class getColumnClass(int column) {
            switch (column) {
            case 0:
            return String.class;
            case 1:
            return String.class;
            case 2:
            return Integer.class;
            case 3:
            return Double.class;
            default:
            return Boolean.class;
            }
            }*/
        };
        table = new JTable(model) {

            private static final long serialVersionUID = 1L;

            @Override
            public Component prepareRenderer(TableCellRenderer renderer, int row, int column) {
                Component c = super.prepareRenderer(renderer, row, column);
                int firstRow = 0;
                int lastRow = table.getRowCount() - 1;
                if (row == lastRow) {
                    ((JComponent) c).setBackground(Color.red);
                } else if (row == firstRow) {
                    ((JComponent) c).setBackground(Color.blue);
                } else {
                    ((JComponent) c).setBackground(table.getBackground());
                }
                return c;
            }
        };
        table.setPreferredScrollableViewportSize(table.getPreferredSize());
        JScrollPane scrollPane = new JScrollPane(table);
        getContentPane().add(scrollPane);
    }
    /*private static String[] suffix = new String[]{"", "k", "m", "b", "t"};
    private static int MAX_LENGTH = 4;

    private static String format(double number) {
    String r = new DecimalFormat("##0E0").format(number);
    r = r.replaceAll("E[0-9]", suffix[Character.getNumericValue(r.charAt(r.length() - 1)) / 3]);
    return r.length() > MAX_LENGTH ? r.replaceAll("\\.[0-9]+", "") : r;
    }*/

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        try {
            UIManager.setLookAndFeel("com.sun.java.swing.plaf.nimbus.NimbusLookAndFeel");
        } catch (Exception fail) {
        }
        SwingUtilities.invokeLater(new Runnable() {

            @Override
            public void run() {
                TablePrepareRenderer frame = new TablePrepareRenderer();
                frame.setDefaultCloseOperation(EXIT_ON_CLOSE);
                frame.pack();
                frame.setLocationRelativeTo(null);
                frame.setVisible(true);
            }
        });
        /*long[] numbers = new long[]{1000, 5821, 10500, 101800, 2000000, 7800000, 92150000, 123200000, 99999900};
        for (long number : numbers) {
        System.out.println(number + " = " + format(number));
        }*/
    }
}
```

Comment: That was not the problem, but it helped me solve the problem! See my answer.

Answer (score 2):

Ok, thanks to [mKorbel's answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/10214573/829571), I realised that I was using `ColorUIResource` instead of `Color`. In other words:

```
label.setForeground(Color.red); //works
label.setForeground(new ColorUIResource(Color.red)); //doesn't work
```

I'm not sure I understand why one works and not the other (`Color` is the direct superclass of `ColorUIResource`), but problem solved.

Comment: +1 for answer, but going wrong direction, for safer way you have to override [NimbusDefault correctly](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/uiswing/lookandfeel/_nimbusDefaults.html#primary), otherwise you could be next person that talking about Buggy Nimbus, notice I agreed that Nimbus isn't good, because progress of development ended somewhere in first quater :-)